# "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filter_ref()"

Tags: wordpress, hosting, dominio

Tengo un dominio, pero al visitar el sitio web, me sale este error, no entiendo por qué. Agradecería muchísimo si me ayudan por favor, soy nuevo en este tema y me recomendaron este foro.

[image: El tal error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apply_filter_ref()" o algo relacionado]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, que de hecho, no es un foro :) Muestra el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, provee más contexto: ¿qué código contiene la línea que se menciona allí? Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Muy probablemente el error te lo esté tirando algún plugin que tienes instalado. Si puedes ingresar al backend puedes desactivar todos los plugins y activarlos de a uno para encontrar el culpable.
Saludos!